# Break on switch cases is like being omitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

A problem occurs while running a switch statement. As you see [each spot is a different case in a switch statement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gt1e.jpg)

When clicking the button of the menu to get some info about the first spot (case 1), [a modal/popup window is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XgTD.jpg), as it should be. But for case 2, two modals are displayed, [it 's like it also triggers case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X55dc.jpg).

Here is the piece of code:

```
function setInfo(hotspot){

switch (hotspot){
    case 1:
        $("#erg").click(function() { 
        $.dialog({
              title: 'Info',
              content: 'Εικονοστάσι στη βάση του βράχου.',
              theme: 'dark',
              offsetTop:'1000',
              boxWidth:'20%',
              useBootstrap: false,
                });
                                   })

        break;

    case 2:
        $("#erg").click(function() { 
        $.dialog({
              title: 'General Info',
              content: 'Content',
              columnClass: 'medium',
              type:'blue',
              useBootstrap: false,
                 });
                })
        break;

    case 3:
        $("#erg").click(function() { 
        $.dialog({
              title: 'Info',
              content: 'Σπηλαιώδες ασκητήριο του Αγίου Γρηγορίου.',
              theme: 'dark',
              offsetTop:'1000',
              boxWidth:'20%',
              useBootstrap: false,
                });
                                   })
        break;


  default:
        $('#screenshot0').css("display", "inline");
        break;
}
```

I'm using a jQuery plugin for the dialog modal. Sorry for the greek characters of its content, thank you very much.

Comment: are you sure "hotspot"  is a number and does it shows any error on console ?

Comment: Are you calling with `1`, seeing 1 dialog then immediately calling with `2` and then click shows two dialogs?   **You are adding more and more click handlers each time you run the code without turning off the old click handlers**.   Run with `2` first and you'll be ok.  Run with `1` twice and you'll get 2 dialogs on 1.

Comment: Note that if you call `setInfo` more than once, more than one listener will be added to the element in question. Else, I guess I would start by `console.log`ging after the `case #`s to see which lines are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding more and more click handlers each time you run the code without turning off the old click handlers.

You can use [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to turn off the previous click handler before adding new ones

```
$("#erg").off("click");
```

updated code:

```js
function setInfo(hotspot) {

  $("#erg").off("click");

  switch (hotspot) {
    case 1:
      $("#erg").click(function() {
        $.dialog({
          title: 'Info',
          content: 'Εικονοστάσι στη βάση του βράχου.',
          theme: 'dark',
          offsetTop: '1000',
          boxWidth: '20%',
          useBootstrap: false,
        });
      })

      break;

    case 2:
      $("#erg").click(function() {
        $.dialog({
          title: 'General Info',
          content: 'Content',
          columnClass: 'medium',
          type: 'blue',
          useBootstrap: false,
        });
      })
      break;

    case 3:
      $("#erg").click(function() {
        $.dialog({
          title: 'Info',
          content: 'Σπηλαιώδες ασκητήριο του Αγίου Γρηγορίου.',
          theme: 'dark',
          offsetTop: '1000',
          boxWidth: '20%',
          useBootstrap: false,
        });
      })
      break;


    default:
      $('#screenshot0').css("display", "inline");
      break;
  }
```